# What claims can be debunked or confirmed by pure logic or theory?

Tags: discussion, answers

Following [Do we apply scientific skepticism at Skeptics.SE?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/do-we-apply-scientific-skepticism-at-skeptics-se) I'm left with a curiosity, but I'd like to learn more. Can you help me out?

According to some we are not using all tools allowed in scientific skepticism, and specifically we're "missing" pure logic arguments, unpublished theoretical proofs and unpublished empirical research.

Restricting this to non-empirical tools, it seems to me that these tools are not really usable in skepticism in general, so here's my doubt.

A factual claim might contain poor logic, however pointing that out does not disprove the claim.

> For example: "Men are taller than women on average, therefore any man is taller than any woman" is not disproven by pointing out the fallacy. Either all men are taller than all women or not.
>
> Another example is debunking any claim of causation due to correlation by pointing out that correlation is not causation (correlation is necessary for causation so certainly it does not disprove it).

It's furthermore obvious that a factual claim which contains solid logic is not necessarily true as its factual premises might be wrong.

> For example: "All introvert people are lonely. All programmers are introverted, therefore programmers are lonely." This claim contains a valid syllogism but showing that doesn't prove that the claim is valid: it does not show that all introverts are lonely, nor that all programmers are introverts, let alone its conclusion.

Equally a claim might be based on a solid theory, but showing that in an answer that does not prove the claim is correct.

> For example: "Do gravitons exist?" can't be answered by simply citing general relativity. While they are predicted by it, we haven't seen any yet and it's perfectly possible that they do not exist, and that we have to change the theory, after all.

The vice-versa is also true:

> If someone claims that a medicine works based on a paper containing mathematical mistakes, showing that it does, does not "prove" that the medicine is ineffective, or that it is effective, nor it "proves" that we don't know whether it works or not.

The above paragraphs are examples of why stating that non-empirical logical/theoretical answers are enough to confirm/debunk a claim seems ...alien to me.

I'd like to know what valid examples people think of, when they state that these tools are allowed in scientific skepticism

Basically, I'd like to know what we are missing.

**Can you think of examples of any on-topic, factual claims that can be settled by pure theory or pure (formal or mathematical) logic?**

Comment: I'm pedantically mentioning "Is Fermat's Last Theorem True?" as an on-topic (!?) factual claim, so that I may dismiss it as a pedantic special-case, where the claim is entirely mathematical, not real-world.

Comment: @Oddthinking would the actual proof to the theorem be a valid skeptical answer? Simon Singh, certainly a skeptic, wrote a whole book on it, and it wasn't the proof itself. OTOH, math theorems can be proven by logic, but I'm not sure the *questions* are on topic. I guess they could be rephrased as "has the fermat theorem been proven?"

Comment: [Has the cure to cancer been hidden by pharmaceutical companies?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/22771/2703)

Comment: @ChrisW Strange comment, yours: in fact, I am asking about questions (but you link to an answer) and furthermore the answer is not of the kind I'm speaking of, as it has 7 references. Maybe you are linking to the wrong post or haven't read my question carefully?

Comment: IMO *that* is a theoretical answer, i.e. a claim settle by theory: it says why, in theory, a conspiracy is implausible. Also the references are merely cosmetic, added *post facto* to satisfy your requirement. Of course you can say, "[yes, but that's not *pure* theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman#Examples)". If you want to insist that pure theory is never sufficient that's OK too: even an example [like this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism#Basic_structure) might need evidence that all humans are mortal and than all Greeks are human.

Comment: Say someone wanted to argue that atmospheric CO2 rises not due to fossil fuel use, but due to degassing from the oceans in response to an increase in global temperatures and that CO2 doesn't cause temperatures to rise.  They demonstrate that CO2 doesn't cause temperatures to rise by showing a graph of increasing CO2 and the "hiatus" in GMSTs.  Pointing out the internal contradiction there ought to be enough to show the hypothesis is faulty.

Comment: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19073/what-was-the-density-of-prehistoric-earth-atmosphere-dinosaurs-buoyancy-theory pointing out that the theory would require medium density wood (e.g. mahogany) to float in mid air is a clearer answer than the one I actually gave (due to the site restrictions) in terms of showing that the theory is wrong.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial that would show their demonstration is incorrect, which doesn't imply the claim is incorrect. Compare with this "I claim that aliens visited earth because they can travel faster than light" being answered with "Nothing can travel faster than light".

Comment: @ChrisW no, I merely note that you are just giving examples of what is allowed. I specifically asked for answers not allowed here but allowed in "scientific skepticism". It seems self evident that answers already allowed here are *not* good examples ;-)

Comment: @sklivvz no, if CO2 depends only on temperature, which is the claim, then a lack of correlation between temperature and CO2 pretty much refutes the claim (doesn't stop people from making it sadly).  It doesn't the other way round as nobody claims that CO2 is the only thing that affects temperature.

Comment: @Sklivvs ChrisW clearly stated the the references were purely cosmetic in order that the answer was permissable.  Under scientific skepticism, the answer would be valid without the cosmetic references.  Cosmetic references can be inserted into pretty much any answer, so if you are going to include that, then the question is meaningless.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial "a lack of correlation between temperature and CO2 pretty much refutes the claim", indeed, but that's a factual statement that is best settled by experiment, or are you arguing that that could be settled otherwise?

Comment: Well I see it as an a edge case: a purely-theoretical answer, apparently a very good/appropriate one (highly up-voted), which was tolerated (i.e. survived) on this site because its author decorated it with references.

Comment: @sklivvz you are not paying attention, the experimental data that refutes the argument is provided as part of the claim.  Note I wrote "They demonstrate that CO2 doesn't cause temperatures to rise by showing a graph of increasing CO2 and the "hiatus" in GMSTs.".  The only thing that need be done is to point out the claim refutes itself.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial We already allow to reference something in the answer when its validity is not in question. Why should we not?

Comment: @Sklivvz do you mean a reference to something in the question?  If so, adding a purely cosmetic reference to the question, just to conform to site rules makes a mockery of the site rules.  We ought to be able to assume the reader can remember the claim long enough to read the answers.

Comment: @ChrisW it's not an edge case at all: it's a theoretical answer which is referenced according to our rules. It's missing some reference for some of its claims but there's a lot of non-cosmetic stuff in there (i.e. stuff which is much more than definitions but directly addresses the points in the answer).

Comment: @DikranMarsupial If a reference is used in a question this doesn't necessarily prevent an answer to use it otherwise. For example if I ask a question about a news article reporting on some experiment, the answerer may refer and use the article itself to answer my question. Clearly, if it's something as trivial as "you didn't read it properly" we are going to close the question as non-notable. But there are cases in which more meaningful questions and answers were given.

Comment: In this case, the basis for the claim ought to appear in the question, so we ought to be able to assume that the reader has seen it already, and no reference is required.

Comment: I think that if it weren't referenced according to our rules then it would still be theoretical, and still an answer (albeit no longer "according to our rules"). Apparently it's not the kind of answer you're looking for here, though, so ...

Comment: @ChrisW this applies to any answer on this site. ever. What can be said with references can always be said without references. What answers are *prevented* by requiring references?

Comment: I think it is worthwhile making a distinction between whether claims can be answered by purely logical means and whether we should change the site rules to allow it.  My answers to those questions would be "yes" and "no" respectively.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial agreed

Comment: I tried to answer your original question, and my answer was converted to a comment. I cannot improve on that answer nor explain it further, so I think that's the end of that; please forgive me if I don't try to address a new/follow-on question i.e. "What answers are *prevented* by requiring references?"

Comment: @sklivvz do you also agree that we are not using all tools allowed in scientific skepticism, and specifically we're "missing" pure logic arguments, unpublished theoretical proofs and unpublished empirical research."?

Comment: I disagree that those arguments are valid skeptical tools (but that's a question on definitions that we should really not reiterate here). I agree that we don't allow them.

Comment: What I am asking here is whether they are useful.

Comment: That seems pretty illogical to me.  To agree that claims can be answered by purely logical means in some cases, but that they are not valid skeptical tools seems like a contradiction to me.  Certainly in science, scientists would be highly skeptical of claims with internal contradictions/inconsistencies!

Comment: I think we're debating what constitutes a claim now. A scientific hypothesis is not a claim, but of course it should be consistent! A scientific law is (supposedly) validated empirically, and thus can only be invalidated empirically. Planets would follow elliptical orbit even if people found mathematical mistakes in Newton's law of gravitation.

Comment: @Slivvz In the example I gave earlier, the error was in the use of the experimental data used in support of the claim.  Sorry, life is too short for these circular discussions.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial Please avoid comments like this. We've noticed repeated examples and they violate our "niceness" policy.

Comment: @Sklivvz Each time you win an argument you get a 'life is too short' response :p

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

> What claims can be debunked or confirmed by pure logic or theory?

Ones where you can point out an *internal* inconsistency in the logical basis for the claim.

Comment: True. So claims like "this is a true demonstration!" can be debunked by "no it isn't, here's the error". Factual claims on the other hand can be true even if the "demonstration" preceding them is inconsistent.

Comment: I gave an example in the comments where the experimental data given as part of the claim are enough to show that the claim is false, hence that point has already been addressed.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial: Yes, I've used the original reference to disprove the claim. In those cases, I have a reference - it just happens to be the one cited in the question.